# How to solve O-Notation over given codeblock example?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I was revising for my algorithm exam and came across one question, which I didn't understand, how to solve it.Here is the example;

```
for (m=0; m<n; m++)
       for (i=1; i<m; i=2*i)  
          [Sequence, Run Time O(1)]
```

I have found that intuitive O(n^2) but I am not sure if it is true.If you guys could explain to me, I would be happy for it.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

While O(n^2) is an upper bound, it's not the tightest you can come up with. That title goes to O(nlog(n)). It's hopefully clear that the internal loop runs log(m) times. So what you get is that the total running time of the function is log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n). Since for all i <= n, we have that log(i) <= log(n), and there are n terms in the sum, we get that the sum is bounded by nlog(n).

Comment: This is incorrect: the inner loop always iterates `log(m)` times, not `log*(m)` times, giving an overall complexity of `ϴ(log(n!)) = ϴ(n log(n))`.

Comment: you're right, I misread 2*i as 2^i for some reason